# How to change $target_dir for uploaded file to an absolute path - website root?

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, plugins

It's a WordPress plugin that enables uploading images. Right now, images are uploaded to: `http://localhost/wp-content/2018/10/image.png`. I want them to be stored in the root of the website. In the main folder where are folders like wp-content, wp-admin and other files.

Here is the code that uploads files to the destination mantioned above.

```
 <div class="wrap">
<h2>Upload files</h2>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select file to upload (Supported files: .rar, .zip, .txt, .xml):
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
</div>
<?php
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $target_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $target_file = $target_dir['path'] . '/' . 
basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType 
!= 
        "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], 
$target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " 
has been 
                uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }

}



}
```

It should be something like: 
/home/user/public_html/ or
/Users/username/Sites/wp/ 
or something similar, but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Are you asking how you do this by directly modifying the code of the plugin? Then what is your actual problem, the line that assigns the value to `$target_dir` is right at the very beginning of the PHP code block there …?

Comment: It's a plugin that I'm writing...

Comment: You can used `get_home_path()`.

Comment: @СрђанСтанишић Did you tried `get_home_path()` instead of `wp_upload_dir()`? Check this link : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_path

Comment: Thanks, I'll try.

Comment: What should I place for $targetFile then? Because get_home_path() returns a string...

Comment: You just need to change this line `$target_file = $target_dir['path'] . '/' . 
basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);` to `$target_file = get_home_path() . '/' . 
basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);`.

Comment: Tahnk you so much. Please place an answer so I can approve it. (If you want)

Comment: Can I ask another question here about the upload file, but different topic? If so, then, the question is: How can I change this code to work with different extensions (file types), not just images? I tried to replace getimagesize() with getfilesize() and change the extensions in if condition, but it isn't working...

Comment: @СрђанСтанишић Please see my answer. Yes, you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this function to get root path [`get_home_path()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_path).

Change this line

```
$target_file = $target_dir['path'] . '/' . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

With below

```
$target_file = get_home_path() . '/' . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed.